# Solving the second order differential equation $y''=y'(2y+1)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

$$y'' = y'(2y+1)$$
with $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=2$.

Could you please help me with the steps for answering this question.

The answer is 
$$y(x)=-\frac{1}{2} \tanh \left( \frac{x}{2}-\arctan (3) \right) -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: **Hint:** Let $$v = y'$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Put $u = y’ \implies \dfrac{u’}{u} = 2y + 1\implies \ln(u) = y^2 + y + C$....

Comment: It's better to specify that $u=u(y)$, it will be more clear to the OP

Answer (score 3):

By inspection, $2y\cdot y' = (y^2)'$

So the entire equation can be integrated once to give $y' = y^2 + y + c$, which can be solved using methods you should already be familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

At first, by integrating you will obtain$$y'=y^2+y+C$$so after applying the initial conditions you have$$y'=y^2+y$$